# How Make Dynamic Zero Filled Number in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

so I was given the task to make a unique code by adding numbers after the code.
and I have tried and succeeded but there is one thing that blocks what if the number has reached its limit? 9999 value
how to reset it to 00001. Lift digit increased by 1

here's my snippet code

```
function getNewCode(value, callback){
    let newCode = _.upperCase(value)  + "-";
    let lastCode = newCode + "0001"

    Transaction.findOne({tr_number: new RegExp(newCode, 'i')}, (err, doc) => {

        if(err) callback(err)
        if (!_.isNil(doc)){
            let arr = doc.tr_number.split("-");

// in this part, i want got some conditional to set a new value 
//when it got max length = 9999 for an example

            let inc = parseInt(arr[1]) + 1;

            lastCode = newCode + ("0000"+inc).slice(-4);
            console.log('lastCode', ciduk, lastCode);

            return callback(lastCode);
        }else{
            return callback(lastCode);
        }
    }).sort({tr_number: -1})
};
```

sorry for my bad language :) grats.

Comment: You seem to be asking a question similar to "how can I use get more than 10000 numbers given a 4 digit decimal integer" which of course is nonsensical.   Perhaps you could restate your requirements to reflect something achievable?

Comment: So this question is impossible? I want when the value reaches the limit 9999 then the next user is 10000, when 99999 becomes 1000000. The digit number increases by 1 each time you reach the limit

Comment: Well, you are slicing off only the last four characters in your code - how would you get anywhere higher than 9999?  10000 will be truncated down to 0000.  If that is not what you want, then why are you only using 4 characters?

Comment: sorry, this is probably because of the series of words that made you confused. I use Google Translate to translate this. but below there is the answer I want. thanks you

Comment: Glad you got a good answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get number size by converting it `toString()` and get it `length`.

```
function getNext(prevStr) {
    let padSize = prevStr.length;
    let next = parseInt(prevStr, 10) + 1;
    if (next >= 10 ** padSize) {
        padSize++;
        next = 1;
    }
    return next.toString().padStart(padSize, '0');
}

console.log(getNext('0099')); // '0100'
console.log(getNext('9999')); // '00001'
```

Comment: thanks bro.. it works! your way of reminding me with exponential mathematical functions, and adding to my knowledge of javascript padstart. very very thank you